# How to pick url id in an ejs template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have created a route as below

```
router.get('/review/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  Question.find({quiz: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}).populate('quiz creator').exec()
  .then(qstn => {
   res.render('review', {
    user: req.user,
    qstn: qstn
  })   
  console.log(qstn);
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
          error: err
      })
  });
 });
```

Now I want to use :id in the ejs template like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<input
  type="hidden"
  id="quiz"
  name="quiz"
  class="form-control"
  value="**I want ID here**"
/>
</div>
```

Any advice on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> You can do it with passing your `id` in your render method.

‍ **For an example** you can look at this code below:

```js
router.get('/review/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    Question.find({
            quiz: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
        }).populate('quiz creator').exec()
        .then(qstn => {
            res.render('review', {
                user: req.user,
                qstn: qstn,
                id: id, // your id it's here
            })
            console.log(qstn);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        });
});
```

After you passing your `id` in your render method, now you can call it in your `ejs` file. It's well looks like this code below:

```
<div class="form-group">
<input
  type="hidden"
  id="quiz"
  name="quiz"
  class="form-control"
  value="<%=id%>"
/>
</div>
```

Now, you can try it and I think it's will working fine.

I hope it can help you .